# Sign of a permutation by homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

[image]

Hello I am countering problem when I tried to prove $\epsilon$ is well defined function.

My try: I defined X be set of two element subsets of {1,2,....,n}. For each f in Sn and every { i, j } in X, I defined f'({ i, j }) =$\frac{ f(j)-f(i)}{(j-i)} $ .  If I show f' is well defined then f will be well defined. I have chosen conventional way to show f' to be well defined. Let { i, j }  and { l,m } be in X and f'({ i, j })=f'({ l, m }). From now I am stuck and don't know how to proceed further. Please give me a hint or something. Thank you

Comment: Your posts will be much more readable if you use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format them

Comment: This seems very confused.  There isn't any question that $\epsilon$ is a well-defined function.  We have an explicit formula for it.  Then you say take $f\in S_n$ and you want to show $f$ is well-defined.  How can there be any question of this?  $f$ is some element of the symmetric group; of course it's a well-defined function.  Then you seem to be starting out to prove that $f'$ is one-to-one, and that seems to have nothing to do with the question.  What you need to show if that if $\sigma, \tau\in S_n,$ then $\epsilon(\sigma\tau)=\epsilon(\sigma)\epsilon(\tau)$

Comment: For $\epsilon$ to be homomorphism it should be function first! That's why I tried to prove that $\epsilon$ is well defined

Comment: Yes, but there is no question that it is well-defined.  An explicit formula is given.  What doubts do you have about its definition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $n=3$ and let $\sigma\in S_3$ be such that $$\begin{align}
\sigma(1)&=2\\
\sigma(2)&=3\\
\sigma(3)&=1
\end{align}$$
Then $$\epsilon(\sigma)=\prod_{1\le i<j\le 3}{\sigma(j)-\sigma(i)\over j-i}=
{\sigma(2)-\sigma(1)\over2-1}{\sigma(3)-\sigma(1)\over3-1}{\sigma(3)-\sigma(2)\over3-2}=\\={3-2\over2-1}{1-2\over3-1}{1-3\over3-2}=1$$

We can perform a similar calulation for any $\sigma\in S_n$ for any $n.$ 
 There is no question that $\epsilon$ is well-defined.  The only choice that is made is the order in which to list the factors in the product, and of course, this doesn't matter.